# Unwanted ads on my web page

Tags: php, html, css

I made a car adverts website with html css and php. I tried several browsers in different locations and on different computers to know how it responded. Everything was perfect, but some computers in internet cafes were displaying some unsolicited ads in Mozilla Firefox together with my legitimate car ads on the same page.

But in the same locations and same computers, Google Chrome, Safari and others were displaying the perfect page I designed unaltered.

What was causing that?
Was that a hack?
What can I do to prevent that?

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Some plugin may have been installed in Mozilla Firefox which was causing the unwanted ads.

Comment: probably computers filled with viruses

Comment: Thank you! I actually contacted my web host. They stated that all codes are ok

Comment: If you got the correct answer, please mark it as correct. This way, you save time from other people in StackExchange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some plugins that installed on browsers that making that effect. You don't have to worry about that if you have not installed any plugin via Javascript in your website.

Comment: those plugins are mostly unwanted, so called "virus" of course you have to worry about that. But it has nothing to do with his website.

Comment: As he have describe he was in Internet caffe, so he has not to worry ;) Anyway, I didn't knew that are considered as viruses. I had a plugin in Chrome that made the same effect, but I remove it a few days later.